# Can't figure out how to use query parameters on JSON object returned from API

Tags: javascript, json, api, query-string

I am trying to figure out how to use query parameters on JSON objects to return specific information. Here is my JSON object, returned from an API i am running on a local server (my mac):

```
[ { "colors"     : [ "Tan", "Chocolate", "Black", "White"] 
  , "_id"        : "5be9c8541c9d440000665243"
  , "name"       : "Norbert"
  , "price"      : 2900
  , "imageUrl"   : "http://localhost:3000/images/teddy_1.jpg"
  , "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
  } 
, { "colors"     : [ "Pale brown", "Dark brown", "White"] 
  , "_id"        : "5beaa8bf1c9d440000a57d94"
  , "name"       : "Arnold"
  , "price"      : 3900
  , "imageUrl"   : "http://localhost:3000/images/teddy_2.jpg"
  , "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
  } 
, { "colors"     : [ "Brown"] 
  , "_id"        : "5beaaa8f1c9d440000a57d95"
  , "name"       : "Lenny and Carl"
  , "price"      : 5900
  , "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
  , "imageUrl"   : "http://localhost:3000/images/teddy_3.jpg"
  } 
, { "colors"     : [ "Brown", "Blue", "Pink"] 
  , "_id"        : "5beaabe91c9d440000a57d96"
  , "name"       : "Gustav"
  , "price"      : 4500
  , "imageUrl"   : "http://localhost:3000/images/teddy_4.jpg"
  , "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
  } 
, { "colors"     : [ "Beige", "Tan", "Chocolate"] 
  , "_id"        : "5beaacd41c9d440000a57d97"
  , "name"       : "Garfunkel"
  , "price"      : 5500
  , "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
  , "imageUrl"   : "http://localhost:3000/images/teddy_5.jpg"
  } 
]
```

My project tells me that there are three endpoints: [image]

I am supposed to use query parameters (definitely NOT dot notation) to get back the following specific information: [image]

I can't see any way of using query parameters. Can anyone understand this? Thank you!!!

Comment: You can't use a query string to directly filter a JSON object. If the parsing is done locally. You are going to have to create a `function()` to parser the return `obj` and get the item you are looking for. On the other hand, if the filter is done by the server, you have to provide the `GET() method()` to filter by. 
What you have there is an `array[]` and you will have to parse it as is, or, run it through `JSON.stringify(obj)` and create a JSON output.

Comment: have you tried to reading response of  something like this url `http://localhost:3000?_id='some_id'` or `http://localhost:3000/some_id` or `http://localhost:3000?name='some_name'` ?

Comment: Query parameters are consumed/processed on the server to determine the intent of the query. Since you control the server, it doesn't sound like you've coded query parameters into the server. On the client you'll have to parse the object yourself.